# create firefox profiles programmatically with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create persistent profiles with firefox, with chrome is enough to provide this

```
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={self.profile_chrome}")
```

but with firefox it's annoyingly different

```
       fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(self.profile_firefox)
```

but I've never seen it working, should I create empty profiles first? the documentation is really not clear on this topic. did anyone find how to do it?

Comment: please check this link, hope it will be helpful: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/100026/selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile

Comment: yes, I've checked all those examples yesterday, but the few with custom directory don't seem to be working with firefox 75 and latest geckodriver

Comment: I think here you can find how to pass options to the Firefox webdriver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769997/selenium-webdriver-firefox-options-what-is-it-about

Comment: no, those will not work