# Selenium throws InvalidArgumentException (Preference values not all string or integer or boolean) when running with Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, frameworks, geckodriver

I'm working within a Selenium and Python test automation framework that uses both Chrome and Firefox. Tests run fine in Chrome, but throw this exception when run with firefox:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Preference values not all string or integer or boolean
```

I cannot show everything, but I belive the error comes from this part of code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=self._driver_path, log_path=Browser.get_log_full_path(self._name))
self._driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=opts)
```

Since I seldomly use firefox, I haven't noticed when exactly this happened, but probably sometime in the last few months, after upgrading geckodriver to 0.30.

I'm using Selenium 4.1.3.

Comment: most likely you are setting opts=webdriver.ChromeOptions() and for firefox its webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

Comment: Hey, thanks, but it is not that, I just copied from the wrong place.

Comment: What happens if you run it headless?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769997/selenium-webdriver-firefox-options-what-is-it-about

Comment: @MacGyver The same.

Comment: Can you post the entire call stack?  This exception extends WebDriverException, so we won't have enough info with just the exception you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it.

The problem was, all the configuration and setup led to this state of `opts.preferences`:

```
{'browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction': 0, 'browser.link.open_newwindow': 3, 'browser.download.folderList': 2, 'browser.download.dir': None, 'intl.accept_languages': 'en'}
```

Setting `browser.download.dir` to an empty string patched the problem, since I don't really use the download directory.